# How Do I Programmatically Left Align Text in a Visio Shape?

Tags: vb.net, visio

Assuming I've created a Rectangle shape and added text:

```
Shape_Obj = Page_Obj.DrawRectangle(1, 1, 2, 2)

Shape_Obj.Text = "Hi, I'm a Rectangle!"
```

By default the text is centered.

I want to left align the text.

How I set TextStyle?

```
Shape_Obj.TextStyle = "???" ' Left align?
```

Plus, what are all of the possible TextStyles I can set? I don't see them listed in the Microsoft pages?

Thanks, Ed

Answer (score 1):

Shape_Obj.CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, visHorzAlign).FormulaU = "0"

Download and install the Visio SDK for full details.

The other values for the paragraph are:

0   Left align      visHorzLeft

1   Center          visHorzCenter

2   Right align     visHorzRight

3   Justify         visHorzJustify

4   Force justify   visHorzForce

[Microsoft Office Visio documentation - HAlign values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/halign-cell-paragraph-section)

Comment: Hi Paul, re: Visio SDK: unfortunately, the development group I'm working in doesn't allow me to download and install third-party packages. However, I followed your suggestion as best as possible. I added an Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisSectionIndices. That got me the definition for visSectionParagraph. I updated my code to: Shape_Obj.CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, 0).FormulaU = "0". The text is still centered in the Rectangle.

Comment: I managed to get it to work.  I defined visHorzLeft = 0. I looked up the value for visHorzAlign which is 6. Then I plugged in the values:         
        Dim S As String
        S = String.Format("{0}", CInt(HAlign_Cell.visHorzLeft)) ' = 0
        Shape_Obj.CellsSRC(visSectionParagraph, 0, 6).FormulaU = S